# Run command using a file over the internet?

Tags: internet, iso

So, I want to run a command on a file without downloading and saving it to my hard drive. I want to use this with the `dd` command to burn an ISO from the internet to a CD. I know I can use other commands such as `wodim`, but I want to use `dd` to burn an iso from the internet directly to `/dev/cdrom` without saving it to my hard drive.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Seriously, how can someone deal with a file that is not even in the computer?

Comment: @EduardoCola According to bodhi.zazen, you can use wget or curl.

Comment: wget and curl will download the file to your hard disk.

Comment: I don't think you can burn a cdrom using dd

Comment: @adonis yes you can.

Comment: @adonis I think you can, but I've heard it makes your CD drive crazy, luckily my CD drive is quiet.

Comment: @Rinzwind, @user245115, i just tried it and i got `dd: failed to open ‘/dev/sr0’: Read-only file system` - maybe there is something wrong with my system...

Comment: nope. you used a  none-writable media

Comment: @Rinzwind - blank cd-rom, i also got the dialog box asking me what do I want to do with it ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use wget (installed by default) or curl (you will have to install curl first)

```
wget -qO-  http://url_of.iso | dd bs=4M of=/dev/cdrom

curl http://url_of.iso | dd bs=4M of=/dev/cdrom
```

Assuming you know the url of the iso and /dev/cdrom is your cd, could be cdrom1 or other ;)

Comment: The OP wants to use dd without downloading the file. Wget does it, so your answer is wrong for this specific question.

Comment: @EduardoCola you have to download the information , the wget options I posted pile the contents of the iso to dd without saving the file on disk

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do something like this:

```
$ dd if=http://server.com/img.iso of=/dev/cdrom
```

But it wont work because dd doesn't understand the http protocol.

You should mount the iso via internet using httpfs2 and then you can use the dd command.

To use httpfs2 you need first to install it (if you didn't already):

```
$ sudo apt-get install httpfs2
```

Then you mount the iso via http in a folder :

```
$ sudo httpfs2 http://server.com/img.iso ~/test
```

And then copy the CD:

```
$ sudo dd if=~/test of=/dev/cdrom
```

Comment: Ok, I haven't even attempted what I was going to do, so I decided to ask how to do it.

Comment: I get an I/O error when attempting this

Comment: In what part of the process do you get the error?
i tested it writing to hdd - didn't want to burn a cd.
( maybe your internet speed couldnt sustain the minimum write speed of the optical drive?) did you use the correct name for your cdrom instead of /dev/cdrom?